# Потокобезопасность вложенных атомарных операций

Tags: java, многопоточность

Класс многопоточного счетчика с максимальным значением.
При вызове метода `incrementNumber()` счетчик увеличивается на 1. При достижении максимума – сбрасывается в 0. Переменные счетчика (counter) и верхний предел (`maximumValue`) – `AtomicInteger`. Верхний предел счетчика может меняться. Если при смене верхнего предела текущее значение счетчика больше предела, то счетчик сбрасывается в ноль.
Будет ли многопоточным следующий метод установки нового максимального значения? Как вообще можно протестировать такой метод на многопоточность?

```java
private final AtomicInteger maximumValue = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

/**
 * Устанавливает максимальное значение счетчика.
 * Если новое максимальное значение меньше текущего значения
 * счетчика, то счетчик обнуляется.
 * @param maximumValue максимальное значение счетчика.
 * @throws NegativeMaximumValueException в случае maximumValue < 0.
 */
public void setMaximumValue(int maximumValue) {
    if (maximumValue >= 0) {
        this.maximumValue.updateAndGet(
                (m) -> {
                    counter.updateAndGet((n) -> n > maximumValue ? 0 : n);
                    return maximumValue;
                });
    } else {
        throw new NegativeMaximumValueException(
                String.format(
                        "Недопустимое значение:%s. Максимальное значение не может быть меньше 0.",
                        maximumValue));
    }
}
```

[Код на github](https://github.com/MaksimJob4j/test_tasks/blob/master/counter/src/main/java/ru/mivanov/counter/IIncrementorImpl.java)

Спасибо!

**Upd:**

Как мне указал в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1021203/309532) [Vladimir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/349747/vladimir) код не верен.

Вариантов вижу два:

1. Заменить maximumValue на int и добавить для него ReadWriteLock (read для incrementNumber() и write для setMaximumValue(..) ) - таким образом удастся заблокировать обновление счетчика при смене максимального значения.
2. Убрать проверку текущего значения счетчика при смене максимального значения и перенести ее в метод getNumber(), заменив код

   ```java
   public int getNumber() {
       return counter.get();
   }
   ```

   на

   ```java
   public int getNumber() {
       return counter.updateAndGet((n) -> n =< maximumValue.get() ? n : 0);
   }
   ```

Какой из вариантов предпочтительней наверное зависит от того, что планируется производить чаще - инкремент счетчика или его запрос. Скорее всего второй вариант в общем случае будет производительней.

Answer (score 1):

Если в вашем счетчике в любой момент времени должен выполнятся инвариант вида:

```
counter.get() <= maximumValue.get()
```

то данный код неверен, т.к может возникнуть ситуация, когда maximumValue поменяется на меньшее, чем было (скажем, было 100, а стало 10), в то время, как сам counter успеет вырасти от 0 до 50 при вызовах инкремента из др. потока.

Т.е. получится:

```
counter.get() = 50
maximumValue.get() = 10
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы правы. Несмотря на то что операция maximumValue.updateAndGet атомарна, она не является блокирующей и счетчик теоретически может вырасти в другом потоке до 50 к моменту установки лимита в 10.

Comment: Остается актуальным вопрос тестирования такого метода. Есть предложения?

Comment: Я бы добавил небольшую искусственную задержку (Thread.sleep) перед "return maximumValue" в методе setMaximumValue() чтобы сымитировать переключение потока в этом месте и тем самым увеличить шанс нарушение инварианта. При этом должно быть несколько потоков, которые делают инкремент и хотя бы один, который делает setMaximumValue() например от 100 до 1 по кругу. Критерий остановки - нарушение инварианта (либо таймаут).

Comment: Пришла еще одна мысль: чтобы проверить инвариант - нужно "одновременно" (атомарно) взять `counter.get()` и `maximumValue.get()`, но это невозможно, т.к. у нас 2 независимые переменные и мы ни на чем не лочимся при доступе к ним. Т.е. мне кажется, проверить инвариант в данной реализации проблематично.

Comment: Проще всего реализовать подобный счетчик через классическую блокировку (с потерей эффективности, конечно по сравнению с CAS) либо подумать в сторону хранения counter и maxvalue в одном `AtomicLong`-e (старшие 4 байта - max, младшие- counter) - тут потребуются пляски с CAS-циклами для апдейта и уменьшится разрядность счетчика с 8 до 4 байт.

Comment: в итоге перенес проверку на непревышение максимума в метод  `getNumber()`. Спасибо про наброс по тестам - буду пробовать (хотелось бы как то протестировать без вмешательство в код метода)! Интересная идея `AtomicLong`!!!

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего сбрасывать. Возвращайте остаток от деления

```
private volatile int maximumValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void setMaximumValue(int maximumValue) {
    if (maximumValue < 0) {
        throw new NegativeMaximumValueException(
                String.format(
                        "Недопустимое значение:%s. Максимальное значение не может быть меньше 0.",
                        maximumValue));
    }
    this.maximumValue = maximumValue;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return counter.get() % (maximumValue + 1);
}
```

Comment: Остаток от деления не пойдет. Скажем если счетчик достиг значения 15 и новый максимум устанавливается на 10, то счетчик по логике задания должен вернуть 0 (а вернет 4).  (